# Bixby Developer Studio keeps asking me to login

Tags: authentication, bixby

When I first launched Bixby Developer Studio, it greeted me with a startup screen with a **Login** button.  I clicked on it and it opened a login page in my browser.  I logged in that page using my Samsung developer account.  The login was successful and a pop-up appeared asking me if I will allow the page to launch Developer Studio (which was already open at that point).  I allowed it, but nothing happened; Developer Studio was still showing the startup screen.

I restarted the application but it again showed me that startup screen with the login button.  If I click on the login button, it will just take me again to the login page in the browser.  And then nothing would happen if I login again.

Comment: More details about your environment might help. Which OS and version? Which browser and version? Are you going through any proxies or vpn gateways?

Comment: @mblakele I'm using Windows 10, Chrome 70.  I am not using any proxy/VPN.  I thought my adblocker was causing the issue but disabling it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest verifying if your browser is configured to accept cookies. If that information is verified and the problem still exists, there might be additional information in the ide.log file that can provide more insight

To get that information, follow these steps:

- Note the time when you begin the next steps.
- Go through the login process until you hit the point of failure.
- From the IDE menu, click on Help -> Create Diagnostics Report. This
  will popup a dialog that will point you to the location of the
  diagnostics report, by default this location is
  C:\Users\'User'\bixby-workspace\
- Unzip the diagnostics report and look at the ide.log file for any
  errors at the time of login.

Feel free to post the errors here or if you prefer, you can open a ticket with Bixby Support too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of points you could work on here -

1. In this case, I suggest you to keep the browser open in the background while clicking on the login button. I was facing the same issue and somehow it worked for me like this. This has been an issue on a Windows machine. On a Mac this problem is not faced till now.
2. You could restart the Bixby studio itself for logging in again.
3. Also, I suggest removing the browser cookies as told by shahnawaz above.

Do let us know if this still persists !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.  For some reason, it just started working right after I received dozens of Windows updates (it's been a few days since I logged in to my Windows account as I have been using Linux; I rarely use my Windows account now and I wish Bixby Studio was available in Linux too).  So, I actually haven't tried any of your suggestions yet.  Thanks again, anyways!